# Open New Page from onLinkTap in Flutter Html Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to navigate to another page when I click on the onLinkTap method.

```
Html(
                data: widget.data['content']['rendered'],
                onLinkTap: (String? url,
                    RenderContext context,
                    Map<String, String> attributes,
                    dom.Element? element) async {
                  print(url);
                  _launchUrl(url!);
                },
              )
```

this is working properly but I want to Navigate to another page instead of _launchUrl.

I am getting this error The argument type 'RenderContext' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.
[image]

Comment: What prevents you to do that?

Comment: @roosi I am getting this error . The argument type 'RenderContext' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution by renaming the RenderContext to renderContext insted of context. and it is worked.